# How to call a function in Woocommerce when order processing email is sent?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter, add-action

I would like to know if there is any way to call a function when a Woocommerce order is successfully placed and the processing order email is sent.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could use the following hook that fires when the order changes to "processing": 'woocommerce_order_status_processing'

So, you can call your function in this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'bbloomer_call_when_processing' );

function bbloomer_call_when_processing() {
    whatever();
}
```